# SQL Server Select Query Is Slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-tuning

I have approx 820,000 records in my SQL Server table and it is taking 5 seconds to select the data from the table. The table has one clustered index on a  time column that could be NULL (as of now it does not contain any NULL value). Why is it taking 5 to 6 seconds to fetch only this much records?

Comment: Please post your table/index definition and query that you are using

Comment: do you mean 8,200,000 records ?

Comment: No just the Columns and the Samples and Code how you retrieve data.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I mean 820,000 records.. sorry for the extra comma

Comment: Hi Khushboo, at a minimum posting a copy of the table schema and index(es) would be required for anyone to provide you with a meaningful answer. If you are pulling 820K records that are 15 varchar(max) in width then I am impressed by your 6 second load time. You could create a SQL Fiddle as well if you would prefer to do that.

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean by 'select the data'? If you are fetching so many records in management studio (displaying all the records) most of this 6 seconds is consumed by showing you all the rows. If it is the case just insert the records to a temp table. It will be much faster.

Comment: By 'select the data' I mean the simple Select statement. Select Column1, Column2, Column3,..... FROM Table1. This is the query I am using.

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you this:

```
1.Check if you are using Clustered and Non-Clustered in you columns (best way I think with a sp_help NameTable).
2.When you using comand "select" specific always all name columns (never use Select * From ..... ).
3.If you are using SSMS check in tools SQL Execution Plan , with this tool you can make simple review your TSQL (you can see cost
each query you make.
4.Dont use "convert(...." in clause WHERE , for example .. Where Convert(int,NameColum)=100.
```